# Is this syntax array inside array?

Tags: c

Below code snippet from Leetcode. the given exercise is to find the longest substring without repeating characters. I am trying to understand the logic from someone has posted the solution

I have below question is

1. I have `cnt` and `s` are array. is this array inside array `cnt[s[j]]` and `cnt[s[j]]++`? how it works, please help to explain. I have tried to visualize the code execution using this

I have tried to understand below line . I tried to visualize the code execution using [image: this site]

```
#include <stdio.h>

int lengthOfLongestSubstring(char * s)
{
    if (s[0] == '\0')
        return 0;
    if (s[1] == '\0')
        return 1;
    
    int i,  j, len, max = 0;
    int cnt[255] = {0}; // array of counter
    //memset(cnt,0,sizeof(cnt));
    for (i=0; s[i]!=0; i++)
    {
        len = 0;
        for (j=i; s[j]!=0; j++)
        {  
            if (cnt[s[j]] == 0)          /* What does this mean since cnt and s both are array? is this called array inside array ? */
            {
                printf("iteration %d  %c\n",j,s[j]);
                cnt[s[j]]++;
                len++;
            }
            else
            { /* if character are not equal */
                break;
            }
        }
        if (len > max)
            max = len;
    }
    return max;
}

int main()
{
    char string1[] = "abcabcbb";
    printf("%d",lengthOfLongestSubstring(string1));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: indexes are pointer arithmetics

Comment: OT: Trouble with "coding competition" sites is the amateur work presented. This program fails when the sample string is "abcabcabcde", reporting longest "substring" without duplicates to be 3...

Answer (score 1):

The syntax `a[b[i]]` means the value in `b[i]` references the index from `a` to read.

So if you have `int a[] = { 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000}; int b[] = { 3, 2, 1, 0};` then `a[b[0]]` resolves to `a[3]` which has the value `10000`.

Note that this requires `b` to only have values that are valid indexes into `a`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an array inside an array, it's using one array to get the subscript into another array.

When you see a complex expression you don't understand, split it up into simpler expressions.

```
cnt[s[j]]++;
```

is roughly equivalent to

```
int charcode = s[j];
cnt[charcode]++;
```

`s` is a string, so `s[j]` contains a character code. So this increments the element of `cnt` corresponding to that character code, and the final result is frequency counts of each character.